# Understanding front-end delete using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-delete

I'm working with a front end `CRUD` RESTful API, and I'm having trouble with `DELETE` and `PUT`.

I know how to do `GET` and `POST`, I have a `forms.html` to post data, and my ajax GET`` call pretty much reloads `localhost:3000/submit/` (my `form.html`page) if formatting is invalid.

My trouble is, I have a Delete button in my front end table (one on each row, created with javascript) and I don't know how to say "onClick, delete this row". I have an app.delete route on my backend, it works like this: `localhost:3000/pokemon/del/7` would delete the 7th entry for example. /del/8 would delete the 8th etc etc. Could I see some documentation or suggestions?

My best guess is this: in JS, create a for loop that will loop through each button and set attribute ("id", "delButton" + j) where j is the var in the for loop. Now i have 6 delete buttons with id's delButton1, delButton2, delButton3 and so on. onClick, ajax delete with url: "http://localhost:3000/pokemon/del/" + j where j is whatever the number is in the button ID. something like that I feel would work, but other than that, I'm not sure.

Comment: Or you could assign something like a `data-id` to the button and use that instead of playing with a `'delButton'` string.

Comment: CRUD and REST are two different things ;) So which one are you working on?

Comment: @DomenikReitzner CRUD

Answer (score 1):

There’s probably about 100 ways of doing this, so this question might get closed as Stack Overflow prefer very defined opinions and solutions, but I’ll throw this in to get you started.

You’re probably not far off at all. A better way of doing it might be to number your rows as they’re created, and use something like `data-row-id` so it doesn’t interfere with actual IDs, as `1` as an ID on an entire page could cause problems later.

Then just add a delete button to each row, with an action that it would get its parent’s `data-row-id` to perform the `DELETE` request, then remove the row when successful.

I’d consider looking into something like Vue or React if you’re going down this road, as they link the view and the data together, so that the table would be a view of the data – when something is removed from the data, the view would update automatically.

Comment: Thanks, this is some great info!

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand right that after Ajax call you just need to delete related row in your table?

If it is that, then you can just pass the button DOM element link to your onClick function

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dn5txhf/)

```
    function deleteRow(el) {
        //do Ajax call
        $.post('/delete',function(){
            $(el).parents('tr').remove();
        }).always(function(){
            $(el).parents('tr').remove();
        })

    }
```